# Estimation of operator norm of the difference between identity and Gram matrix?

Tags: operator-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, frame-theory

I have a "tall" matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$, $N>n$, with its operator norm being upper-bounded by some constant $C>0$, i.e., $\|W\|_{2\rightarrow 2}\leq C$. What I am trying to estimate, is the quantity
\begin{equation}
\|I-aWW^T\|_{2\rightarrow 2},\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
where $a$ is simply another constant $a>0$. Is it possible to acquire an upper bound of (1) in terms of, e.g., C (and $a$)? Because the simple use of the triangle inequality seems quite coarse.

I'm sorry a priori if it's some elementary stuff, but I haven't practice linear algebra for quite a long time and didn't find anything relevant online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $W$ has rank at most $n$, the same is true for $WW^T$.

The matrix $aWW^T$ is positive semidefinite, so its eigenvalues are nonnegative and its largest eigenvalue is $\|aWW^T\|=a\,\|W\|^2$.

The matrix $I-aWW^T$ is selfadjoint (real, symmetric), and so its operator norm is the largest eigenvalue in absolute value. Its eigenvalues are of the form $1-\lambda$ with $\lambda$ an eigenvalue for $aWW^T$. The largest eigenvalue in absolute value for $I-aWW^T$ is then
$$
\max\{\lambda_\max-1, 1-\lambda_\min\}.
$$
In this case, because the rank of $aWW^T$ is at most $n<N$, we know that $\lambda_\min=0$. Thus
$$
\|I-aWW^T\|\leq\max\{a\,\|W\|^2-1,1\},
$$
and this inequality is sharp.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and help Martin!